# React Native: Opening push notification opens app but does not navigate to related content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Currently when opening a push notification while the app is running, it will navigate to the correct content scene.  When the app is closed however, and a user opens a push notification it will just open the app and not navigate to the related content scene.  I think the problem has to do with the onNotification function firing around the same time as the checkLogin function.  I would like to somehow wait until the checkLogin is finished and continue running onNotification.  I appreciate anyones help.

```
// When receiving an incoming notification (iOS/Android)
onNotification: async function (notification) {

//for iOS the data is nested, for Android the data is attached directly to the object
  let data = (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? notification.data : notification;
  let id = data._id;
  let channelId = data.channel;
  let message = data.message;

  Logger.info('Notification Received', message);

  if (isLoggedIn()) {
    // Check if the logged in user is the one who received the message
    let content = ModelCache.getContent(id);

    Navigation.goContent(content);
  }
},
```

This block of code is on the index file when the app boots up.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.checkLogin();
}

async checkLogin() {
  let user = await Data.getStoredUser();
  this.setState({
    isUserChecked: true,
    initialRoute: user ? Navigation.MAIN_SCENE : Navigation.LANDING_SCENE
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's javascript, it is unlikely that one thing is occurring at the same time as another thing, so therefore it likely means that your `onNotification` is being called before your `checkLogin` function. Perhaps a workaround would be to set a value in the state from within `onNotification` which could be referenced and acted upon by `checkLogin`.

Comment: can you show me an example of how to set the value in the state from onNotification?

Comment: You didn't mention using redux so if you're just using component state, I would simply define onNotification from within the top level component itself, perhaps in componentDidMount for example, and then have access to `this.setState` from within it.